# Верификация устройства через одноразовый пароль

Tags: android, авторизация, клиент-сервер

Схема работы: при авторизации на новом устройстве, сервер отправляет одноразовый пароль в уже авторизованное на другом устройстве приложение (например  Telegram, только в моем случае это не мессенджер).

Вопрос в том, как в авторизованном приложении отловить получение такого кода, чтобы отобразить его?

Comment: Дайте конкретное описание приложения, которое должно отлавливать полученные пароли. Не совсем ясен метод и тип отправки.

Comment: Пароль будет генериться на сервере в ответ на запрос авторизации с нового устройства и отправляться на android приложение. Приложение - клиент на андроид, Или какое конкретное описание необходимо?

Comment: Вам 9 лет ? вы мысли свои излагать умеете ? 2 клиента подключаются к серверу под одним и тем же паролем, так ? и 1му нужно сообщить что подключился кто то еще ? при чём тогда одноразовый пароль ?

Comment: Когда Вы регистрируетесь в telegram или любом другом мессенджере, вам нужно ввести код, который присылается на другое ваше устройство. Мне нужно сделать примерно тоже самое. Двухфакторная авторизация такая, только без смс